# VBA Script to keep from recording duplicate records

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that I have created in Excel as an input area for Production Information. Once the data has been filled into the Form I have a save button with a macro behind it. This to copy and paste the data from the form into a line in the Info Log area below the form.

I have tried to use a "helper" column to place True if the information being saved has already been saved once. I am not sure I have all of that correct either.

```
Sub Record_Save()
'With Sheets("Roll Line Form")
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Range("B43:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = 
        "=CountIf(D2:D4,D2,)>1"
    'Range("B:B").AutoFilter 1, "True"
'If .Range("B:B").Value = "True" Then
   'MsgBox "This has already been entered"
'Exit Sub
'End If
'End With
With Sheets("Roll Line Form")
If .Range("D2").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Date"
    Exit Sub
End If
RecordRow = .Range("C999999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Find First Available Row
For RecordCol = 3 To 46
.Cells(RecordRow, RecordCol).Value = .Range(.Cells(41, 
RecordCol).Value).Value
Next RecordCol
End With
End Sub
```

I want to have the Macro understand that the data is already saved and not to save the data in the Log area. I have commented out the code I tried to use but when it was still running I would get the error code of Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object error
This is on the line that starts Range ("B43:B"...

Comment: Instead of doing all that worksheet manipulation you could do everything in arrays. I also dont see how youre checking for preexisting values.

Comment: Doug you are 100% correct sir. I do not know how to get that done. That is probably a better question to ask.